# pthread_cancel() does not cancel a thread as it should

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, posix

I am testing a signal handler for my OS Class project.
Basically my signal handler (which is running in it's own thread) have to handle SIGINT, this means that it has to "kill" all the other threads and then exit.

unfortunately my code does not work.

This is my dummy thread task, which I want to stop with a SIGINT

```
 static void * dummyTask(){
   pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
   pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, NULL);
   while(1){
      pthread_testcancel();
      printf(" Hello!\n");
      sleep(2);
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

Here is my main. As you can see I create the signal handler and then up to 2 dummy threads.
I save their thID in an array, I need this later in the task of the signal handler thread, as you will see

```
 int main(){
   //need to the signal handler thread, so it can kill all the threads with cancel
   pthread_t **thids = malloc( 2 * sizeof(pthread_t *));
   sigset_t set;
   pthread_t signalHandlerThread;

   sigemptyset(&set);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
   //s is for error checking, not importanto now
   int s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

   //shParam: signalHandlerParam
   signalHParam *shParam = malloc(sizeof(signalHParam));
    shParam->set = &set;
    shParam->arrayOfThIDs = thids;
   s = pthread_create(&signalHandlerThread, NULL, signalHandlerTask, (void *) shParam);

   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
     pthread_t dummyThread;
     pthread_create(&dummyThread, NULL, &dummyTask, NULL);
     thids[i] = &dummyThread;
   }

   pause();
   //pthread_join(signalHandlerThread, NULL);
   return 1;
}
```

As you can see the signalHandlerThread execute a function named signalHandlerTask, which is:

```
static void *signalHandlerTask(void *shParam){
   signalHParam *tmp = (signalHParam *) shParam;
   sigset_t *set = tmp->set;
   int s, sig;

    int i = sigismember(set, SIGINT);
    if(i != 1)
      printf("error\n");
   while(1 == 1){
      s = sigwait(set, &sig);
        
        if(sig == SIGINT){
            printf("\n----- signal recived ----\n");
         //function that use the array to kill threads
            killThreads(tmp->arrayOfThIDs);
            pthread_exit(NULL); //kill the signal handler thread
        }
    }
}
```

The shParam is a struct that I use to pass multiple arguments to the task of the thread (signalHandlerTask) and it is like this

```
typedef struct{
   pthread_t **arrayOfThIDs;
   sigset_t *set;
} signalHParam;
```

Finally we are at the real issue. I created the killThreads function as follows:

```
void killThreads(pthread_t **thids){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        int r = pthread_cancel(*thids[i]);
        if(r != 0)
            printf("error!! %d\n", r);
            //r is 3, why??
            pthread_join(*thids[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

The problem is, as said, that `pthread_cancel(*thids[i])` not work, threads are left alive and I can't figure out why

Here is the entire code for those who wants to run it:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct{
   pthread_t **arrayOfThIDs;
   sigset_t *set;
} signalHParam;

void killThreads(pthread_t **thids){
    //termino il threadListener, e tutti i thread nel thread pool 
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

        //FAI ANCHE SU PROGETTO!!
        int r = pthread_cancel(*thids[i]);
        if(r != 0)
         printf("pthread_cancel failed: %s\n", strerror(r));
        //FAI ANCHE SU PROGETTO!!
        pthread_join(*thids[i], NULL);
    }

}

static void *signalHandlerTask(void *shParam){
    signalHParam *tmp = (signalHParam *) shParam;
   sigset_t *set = tmp->set;
   int s, sig;

    int i = sigismember(set, SIGINT);
    if(i != 1)
      printf("error\n");
   while(1 == 1){
      s = sigwait(set, &sig);
        
        if(sig == SIGINT){
            printf("\n----- signal recived ----\n");
         //function that use the array to kill threads
            killThreads(tmp->arrayOfThIDs);
            pthread_exit(NULL); //kill the signal handler thread
        }
    }
}
static void * dummyTask(){
   pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
   pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, NULL);
   //printf("mo aspetto 10s\n");
   //sleep(10);
   while(1){
      pthread_testcancel();
      printf(" Ciao!\n");
      sleep(2);
   }
   return NULL;
}

int main(){
   //need to the signal handler thread, so it can kill all the threads with cancel
   pthread_t **thids = malloc( 2 * sizeof(pthread_t *));
   sigset_t set;
   pthread_t signalHandlerThread;

   sigemptyset(&set);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
   //s is for error checking, not importanto now
   int s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

   //shParam: signalHandlerParam
   signalHParam *shParam = malloc(sizeof(signalHParam));
    shParam->set = &set;
    shParam->arrayOfThIDs = thids;
   s = pthread_create(&signalHandlerThread, NULL, signalHandlerTask, (void *) shParam);

   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
     pthread_t dummyThread;
     pthread_create(&dummyThread, NULL, &dummyTask, NULL);
     thids[i] = &dummyThread;
   }

   pthread_join(signalHandlerThread, NULL);
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: This probably isn't your only problem (which is why this isn't an answer), but `thids` should be an array of `pthread_t`, not an array of `pthread_t *`.  You are reusing the _same_ `pthread_t` object over and over again to create all the threads; each call to `pthread_create` overwrites the previous thread handle and so you lose the ability to cancel all but one of the threads.

Comment: Also, the value returned by `pthread_cancel` is an `errno` code: change `printf("error!! %d\n", r)` to `printf("pthread_cancel failed: %s\n", strerror(r))` and you'll get a more helpful error message.  (I don't know what code 3 means on your operating system so I can't just tell you.) (You need to include `string.h` for `strerror`.)

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help you if you posted a _complete_ program that we could compile ourselves and tinker with. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: @zwol You're right about the unnecessary `pthread_t *`, I'll change that later. About reusing the same  `pthread_t`, I've moved hte  `pthread_t dummyThread` inside the  `for`, this way the "variable"  `dummyThread` is always "new" (Actually I still think that saving the pointer in the array should work..)

Comment: @zwol About the 'sterror(r)', the output is: `pthread_cancel failed: No such process`. I am going to add a pastebin link for the whole file, so you can run it. (I actually think that this way it is more clear to understand my code)

Comment: *About reusing the same pthread_t, I've moved hte pthread_t dummyThread inside the for, this way the "variable" dummyThread is always "new" (Actually I still think that saving the pointer in the array should work..)* -- This is valid reasoning for some other languages, but C doesn't work that way. I don't think I can fit an explanation of what C actually does into the comment box, but as long as you aren't making an actual copy of the `pthread_t` object into the array, your code will still be broken in this way.

Comment: Which thread is failing to cancel? Dummy or sig handler?

Comment: You're right that presenting fragments of the program makes it easier to understand what your problem is.  You did a good job with that.  However, we do still need to see the whole program in case the problem is in a piece you didn't think to show us, and please don't use pastebin to do that.  Instead, copy and paste it into the very bottom of your question.  (Did you know you can edit your question?  The tiny gray word "edit" under the tags is a button.  Yes, it's bad UI design.  Sorry.)  We want this to make sense years from now, which means not relying on external links that may expire.

Comment: @zwol Oh I see. I edited the post with a pastebin links, I'll remove it and post the entire file at the end, as you suggest. Thank you very much man

Comment: @charlesw The sigHandler thread have to cancel the dummy threads, but the sigHanlder has no success in his quest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having run the full program myself, it turns out that the only important bug is the one I originally pointed out in the comments.  (There are a bunch of style problems and places where I wouldn't have done it that way, but none of them rises to the level of "bug".  There *is* one minor unrelated bug: you forgot to include `stdio.h` and `signal.h`.)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
  pthread_t dummyThread;
  pthread_create(&dummyThread, NULL, &dummyTask, NULL);
  thids[i] = &dummyThread;
}
```

This creates a single variable named `dummyThread` (whether or not it is declared inside the loop) and writes *all* of the thread handles into that variable.  All of the `thids[i]` pointers are set to point to that one variable.  Since a single `pthread_t` variable can only hold a single thread handle, you lose the thread handles created on all but the last iteration of the loop.  Later, the signal handler thread will attempt to cancel the same thread repeatedly, will succeed the first time, and fail the remaining N-1 times.  (To make it more obvious what's going on, increase the number of threads and notice that the program prints "pthread_cancel failed: No such process" exactly N-1 times, no matter what N is.)

The correction is simply to use an array of `pthread_t` instead of an array of `pthread_t *`, and write the thread handles directly into the array:

```
typedef struct{
   pthread_t *arrayOfThIDs;
   sigset_t *set;
} signalHParam;

void killThreads(pthread_t **thids){
    //termino il threadListener, e tutti i thread nel thread pool 
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        //FAI ANCHE SU PROGETTO!!
        int r = pthread_cancel(thids[i]);
        if(r != 0)
         printf("pthread_cancel failed: %s\n", strerror(r));
        //FAI ANCHE SU PROGETTO!!
        pthread_join(*thids[i], NULL);
    }

}

// ...

int main(){
   //need to the signal handler thread, so it can kill all the threads with cancel
   pthread_t *thids = malloc( 2 * sizeof(pthread_t));
   sigset_t set;
   pthread_t signalHandlerThread;

   sigemptyset(&set);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
   //s is for error checking, not importanto now
   int s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

   //shParam: signalHandlerParam
   signalHParam *shParam = malloc(sizeof(signalHParam));
    shParam->set = &set;
    shParam->arrayOfThIDs = thids;
   s = pthread_create(&signalHandlerThread, NULL, signalHandlerTask,
                      (void *) shParam);

   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
     pthread_create(&thids[i], NULL, &dummyTask, NULL);
   }

   pthread_join(signalHandlerThread, NULL);
   return 1;
}
```

`signalHandlerTask` and `dummyTask` are basically correct as-is.

Comment: Awesome, I really didn't think that that was the real problem, I tought it was just a design error to solve but not influent. Great. I tried to create 4 dummy threads and to kill just of them, it works perfectly! Thx mate